# Perl CGI Form Post input script not working

Tags: html, perl

I am trying to create a webpage on my site that takes input from a form (firstname,lastname) and process this input via a PERL CGI script and write that input to a file.

I would also like the page after script runs to display a message stating it successfully completed with links to get back to the homepage.

I am pretty sure my HTML page is correct when referencing the script so I will just post my perl script below.

Thanks in advance.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict; use warnings;
use CGI::Carp qw('fatalsToBrowser'); # send errors to the browser, not to the logfile
use CGI;

print header "Content-Type: text/html\n\n";

print start_html ("Receive Form Post");

my $datestring = localtime();
my $fname = param('firstname');
my $lname = param('lastname');

open (TESTFILE, '>>c:\inetpub\wwwroot\logfiles\bwrigsbee.txt') or die;

print TESTFILE "This file has been successfully edited on $datestring\n";
print TESTFILE "by $fname $lname\n";

close (TESTFILE);

print end_html;
```

HTML Form that is in the page that calls the script:

```
   <form action="logwrite.pl" method="POST">
    <table style="width:400px" border=1px border=solid border=black>
        <tr>
            <td>First name: <input type="text" name="firstname"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Last name: <input type="text" name="lastname"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Submit"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
   </form>
```

Debug info from browser--->
Undefined subroutine &main::param called at C:\studentwebusers\CIS33715\logwrite.pl line 11.

Comment: Post your html.  You want to make sure that you are actually posting to the script in your `<form action=''`  Also, the content-type is important.  Is the request even getting to the script?  Also, check your permissions

Comment: I have the action correct, when I submit the form it brings me to a debug page that references errors in the script. However this is my first experience with perl and CGI and I have no idea what I am doing so I am no good at debugging.

Comment: What errors?  What do those errors say?

Comment: First off, your html is not valid `    <table style="width:400px" border=1px border=solid border=black>`  Your style is malformed.

Comment: @Zuzlx, the HTML is indeed malformed, but this does not affect the functional issue that the question is about.

Comment: @Korpeia.  I know.  I'm still waiting for the errors that the sees.

Comment: I am not worried about the table style, I have removed all style from the table... I am concerned with the CGI script. I will edit the original post with the debug information as you requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the single quotes in your use `CGI::Carp` call:

```
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);
```

Also, your call to `header` should not include the additional parameters.  It could accept a type 'text/html' but all the additional info is an error

```
print header;
```

Use [`autodie`](http://perldoc.perl.org/autodie.html) anytime you're doing file processing.  That way you won't have to be bothered to create detailed error messages.  And use the 3 parameter form of `open` with lexical finel handles.

Finally, go ahead and use the object notation for all of methods in `CGI`.   That will change your script to the following:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser); # send errors to the browser, not to the logfile
use CGI;

my $q = CGI->new;

print $q->header;
print $q->start_html("Receive Form Post");

my $datestring = localtime();
my $fname = $q->param('firstname');
my $lname = $q->param('lastname');

open my $fh, '>>', 'c:\inetpub\wwwroot\logfiles\bwrigsbee.txt';
print $fh "This file has been successfully edited on $datestring\n";
print $fh "by $fname $lname\n";
close $fh;

print $q->end_html;
```

Comment: I believe your code here corrected the issue with the CGI script not working... Thank you much.

Now I need the script to point back to the original HTML file with edits to the body thanking them for their input...